Give Levitation to player wearing helmet with custom model data
I want to give Levitation 20 to all players who wear a helicopter hat (a retextured leather helmet), with custom_model_data=6. So far it gives Levitation to anyone who wears a leather helmet.
Here is the command to give the helmet:
give @s leather_helmet[
   custom_model_data=6,
   item_name='{"bold":true,"color":"green","text":"Helicopter Hat","underlined":true}',
   lore=[
      '{"bold":true,"color":"aqua","text":"This hat makes you go BRRR!!!"}'
   ],
   unbreakable={
      
   },
   fire_resistant={
      
   },
   rarity="uncommon",
   enchantments={
      levels:{
         "minecraft:projectile_protection":10
      }
   },
   attribute_modifiers=[
      {
         id:"55727382-8d6f-41bb-8ce6-d6c35f7dfa40",
         type:"generic.fall_damage_multiplier",
         amount:0,
         operation:"add_multiplied_base",
         slot:"head"
      },
      {
         id:"safe_fall_distance",
         type:"generic.safe_fall_distance",
         amount:99999,
         operation:"add_value",
         slot:"head"
      }
   ]
] 1

This is the command that give the effect:
execute if entity @a[
   nbt={
      Inventory:[
         {
            Slot:103b,
            id:"minecraft:leather_helmet"
         }
      ]
   }
]run effect give @a[
   nbt={
      Inventory:[
         {
            Slot:103b,
            id:"minecraft:leather_helmet"
         }
      ]
   },
   
] 
levitation 1 20

This is coded in Visual Studio, for a data pack. I put this in tick.mcfunction. This is for Minecraft Java Edition 1.21.

Hi Bbronse, please see the tag info page for Minecraft commands here a good look, to see if you can provide more information. Thanks!

What exact information do you need, as the things it says to add are what I've tried that failed, which are all failed attempts at detecting when the player is wearing a specific helmet, and I cant find the command to do so anywhere for 1.21. Thank you for your time.
